# Scala Case Class Tupled

Tags: scala, case-class

How can I call the tupled method on this case class?

```
case class(a: Int, b: String)(c: String, d: Int)
```

The reason why I have my case class like this is because I want to use only the first two parameters to be considered for equals and hashCode comparison!

So how can I properly call the tupled on such a case class?

Comment: Why do you want this to be a case class? Case classes have some convenience features, but the payback for this is some loss of flexibility. Just define your own class and override equals/hashCode yourself.

Comment: Yes, I understand but I do some heavy pattern matching on this case class, so I have to leave it as a case class!

Comment: Maybe you want to rename your question to smth like "Scala Case Class Multiple Parameter Lists" instead of Tupled

Comment: Then write yourself an unappply method. There's nothing really magic about case classes, you can do the equivalent yourself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short it does not seem like a good idea to use case classes this way. Here is an explanation.

Let's check the class declaration together with generated `apply` and `unapply`:

```
scala> case class A(a: Int, b: String)(c: String, d: Int)
defined class A

scala> A.apply _
res0: (Int, String) => (String, Int) => A = <function2>

scala> A.unapply _
res1: A => Option[(Int, String)] = <function1>
```

You can see that although `apply` takes 4 arguments in total (curried), `unapply` discards second list.

Let's see if we can access members of the second list:

```
scala> val a = A(1, "two")("three", 4)
a: A = A(1,two)

scala> a.a
res2: Int = 1

scala> a.c
<console>:11: error: value c is not a member of A
              a.c
                ^
```

... nope, not a regular way. Let's check couple more properties:

```
scala> a.productArity
res4: Int = 2

scala> a.productIterator.toList
res5: List[Any] = List(1, two)
```

Ok, it seems like second argument list is pretty much ignored. Let's dig in:

```
scala> :javap A
...
  public int a();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #16                 // Field a:I
         4: ireturn
...
  public java.lang.String b();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #21                 // Field b:Ljava/lang/String;
         4: areturn
...
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
     ... //mentions only a and b:....
        32: invokevirtual #32                 // Method a:()I
        35: aload         4
        37: invokevirtual #32                 // Method a:()I
        40: if_icmpne     88
        43: aload_0
        44: invokevirtual #35                 // Method b:()Ljava/lang/String;
        47: aload         4
        49: invokevirtual #35                 // Method b:()Ljava/lang/String;
...
  public A(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int);                                                                 
    descriptor: (ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V                                                                 
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC                                                                                                     
    Code:                                                                                                                 
      stack=2, locals=5, args_size=5                                                                                      
         0: aload_0                                                                                                       
         1: iload_1                                                                                                       
         2: putfield      #16                 // Field a:I                                                                
         5: aload_0                                                                                                       
         6: aload_2                                                                                                       
         7: putfield      #21                 // Field b:Ljava/lang/String;                                               
        10: aload_0                                                                                                       
        11: invokespecial #100                // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V                                     
        14: aload_0                                                                                                       
        15: invokestatic  #106                // Method scala/Product$class.$init$:(Lscala/Product;)V                     
        18: return                                                                                                        
      LocalVariableTable:                                                                                                 
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature                                                                             
            0      19     0  this   LA;                                                                                   
            0      19     1     a   I                                                                                     
            0      19     2     b   Ljava/lang/String;                                                                    
            0      19     3     c   Ljava/lang/String;                                                                    
            0      19     4     d   I
```

So there is no use of `c` and `d` in constructor or in equals.

You can still make second arg list params useful by prefixing them with `val`:

```
scala> case class B(a: Int, b: String)(val c: String, val d: Int)         
defined class B                                                           

scala> val b = B(1, "two")("three", 4)                                    
b: B = B(1,two)                                                           

scala> b.c                                                                
res6: String = three                                  

scala> b.d                                                                
res8: Int = 4
```

Let's see how equality and hashcode works in this case:

```
scala> val b2 = B(1, "two")("no the same", 555)
b2: B = B(1,two)

scala> b == b2
res10: Boolean = true

scala> b.hashCode
res13: Int = -1563217100

scala> b2.hashCode
res14: Int = -1563217100
```

Seems to work the way you want it to, which I personally don't like ;)

For completeness, default pattern matching is still the way it was for class `A`:

```
scala> B.unapply _
res15: B => Option[(Int, String)] = <function1>
```

Scala language spec explains how it works [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-members).

> The formal parameters in the first parameter section of a case class
>   are called elements; they are treated specially. First, the value of
>   such a parameter can be extracted as a field of a constructor pattern.
>   Second, a val prefix is implicitly added to such a parameter, unless
>   the parameter carries already a val or var modifier. Hence, an
>   accessor definition for the parameter is generated.

and

> Every case class implicitly overrides some method definitions of class
>   scala.AnyRef unless a definition of the same method is already given
>   in the case class itself or a concrete definition of the same method
>   is given in some base class of the case class different from AnyRef.
>   In particular:
>
> - Method **equals**: (Any)Boolean is structural equality, where two instances are equal if they both belong to the case class in question
>     and they have equal (with respect to equals) constructor arguments
>     (**restricted to the class's elements, i.e., the first parameter
>     section**).
> - Method hashCode: Int computes a hash-code. If the hashCode methods of the data structure members map equal (with respect to equals)
>     values to equal hash-codes, then the case class hashCode method does
>     too.
> - Method toString: String returns a string representation which contains the name of the class and its elements.

Comment: Just for completeness (given that this answer does not even mention `tupled`), the way to get the tupled function, as requested,  would be something like that: `val tupled = (A.apply _).tupled.andThen(_.tupled)`. Note though that it takes **two** tuples as parameters (by example you'd do : `tupled( (123, "foo" ) )( ("bar", 456) )`). Transforming that into a function taking only one single tuple (in your case a `Tuple4`) cannot be achieved out of the box without destructuring the tuples, so at that point you should as well write the tupled method entirely manually.

Comment: Basically: case class magic applies only to the first parameter list.

Comment: Not only that, but also if the constructor cannot be implicitly converted to a plain function (via eta-expansion), then the companion won't extend `FunctionN` and you won't get the `tupled` method on it. This includes case classes with multiple parameter lists, generic case classes, case classes with varargs etc.